# How does amorphous $\rm SiO_2$ crystallize?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, insulators, amorphous-solids

I know crystalline  $\rm SiO_2$ changes its crystalline structure depending on temperature, but what happens to amorphous  $\rm SiO_2$ if you heat it up? I could find nothing on this topic. Is it similar to Si, which becomes polycrystalline if you go to high enough temperatures? If not, how is crystalline  $\rm SiO_2$ formed?

Comment: Yes, it will crystallize when heated, and precisely which crystal structure depends on the temperature you heat it to. In the deep dark past I've shattered amorphous SiO2 light pipes when self-focusing heated an interior portion above the crystallization temperature, inducing a rapid volume change... But, you need to think of a time-temperature-transformation family of curves to crystallize.

Comment: Does anyone have a source/a graph of what happens at which temperature (pressure/temperature curve)? I could not find one where the initial state is amorphous.

Comment: DOI: 10.1038/s42004-018-0049-4 Nucleation of quartz under ambient conditions Phil Buckley1, Natasha Hargreaves1 & Sharon Cooper1 might be a place to start (Nature paper). Lots of work with oxides of various purities, over the last century plus...